# leiningen: missing super-pom

Tags: clojure, maven, leiningen

if I enable eith the clojure-couchdb or swank-clojure then `lein deps` fails because org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0 is missing

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.1.0-master-SNAPSHOT"]
               [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.0-SNAPSHOT"]
               [clojure-http-client "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"]
               [org.apache.activemq/activemq-core "5.3.0"]
;              [org.clojars.the-kenny/clojure-couchdb "0.1.3"]
;              [org.clojure/swank-clojure "1.1.0"]
              ])
```

this error:

```
  Path to dependency: 
1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0
2) org.clojure:swank-clojure:jar:1.1.0

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
 org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0

from the specified remote repositories:  
  clojars (http://clojars.org/repo/),
  clojure-snapshots (http://build.clojure.org/snapshots),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

what is super-pom. why do these packages need it and where can I get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this just means that Maven wasn't able to satisfy the dependencies you specified. I've checked there's no `org.clojure/swank-clojure` artifact in any of the three repositories your message mentions. For clojure-couchdb, the version you're using -- as far as I can tell from looking at [its project.clj file on GitHub](http://github.com/the-kenny/clojure-couchdb/blob/master/project.clj) -- depends on `org.clojure/clojure-http-client "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"`, which doesn't exist in the repos either.

One way around this problem is to install the jars you want into your local repo. (<strike>I can't seem to remember the exact command... will look it up in a minute.</strike> See e.g. [this page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) for instructions.) Then Maven will just pick them up from there.

(BTW, if you want to use Clojure + contrib 1.1.0, you can just use `"1.1.0"` as the version strings now. That's for both `org.clojure/clojure` and `org.clojure/clojure-contrib`.)

Oh, and about the super POM -- from [this page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM) in Maven's docs:

> The Super POM is Maven's default POM. All POMs extend the Super POM unless explicitly set, meaning the configuration specified in the Super POM is inherited by the POMs you created for your projects.

As for how it got into your error message, I've honestly no idea. You could add the "maven" tag to this question or just ask a separate question with that tag to get some Maven gurus onto it.

Comment: Incidentally, not sure if this should be part of the answer proper, but if you're including a Swank dependency just to use `lein swank`, you should use a `leiningen/lein-swank "1.1.0"` instead. Also, put it in your `:dev-dependencies` (note they're still included in e.g. uberjars for now, but perhaps some day lein will be smarter...).

Comment: i'm actually using both. leain swank as a buld dep and swank for a "remote control" into the running server. (that will probibly go when we ship this) swank is officially neeto!

Comment: That's true enough. :-) For an embedded swank, you can use a `swank-clojure "1.1.0"` dependency; see http://clojars.org/repo/swank-clojure/swank-clojure/ for a list (of sorts) of the available versions. I've tested this with `lein deps` and it works fine!

Comment: Ok, I think I've got an idea which may work for you... How about putting `org.clojure/clojure-http-client` on the `:exclusions` list in `lein` and have your project explicitly depend on `clojure-http-client` (I think no groupId is required; the current version on Clojars seems to be `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`)? This way `clojure-couchdb` should be able to find all the `clojure-http-client`'s namespaces it needs while lein / Maven will be able to fetch your deps. I think you'll have to run some code using `clojure-couchdb` to test this; let me know how it works out.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's still common that projects have broken dependencies.  It's unfortunate, because it really mars the experience.

My solution is to go onto http://clojars.org and search for the library I need.  Usually there are a few versions.  I do a little research on http://github.com to see which one is most up to date.  Then I try that one as a dependency.  If it works, great!  Otherwise, I try another one.

It's a long process, but I think it is getting better.  You should have seen the process before!

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error on the maven super-pom dependency, and when I do

```
$ sudo lein deps
```

It runs without error. Not an ideal solution, but it works for me.

Comment: sudo lein deps will install the deps to /root/.m2 instead of /home/you/.m2/ you would likely get the same result by first deleting /home/you/.m2/?

Comment: I have no /root on my Mac, but at least removing .m2 fixed it. I also had to re-install Leiningen of course.

Comment: See my solution.  As sudo runs in a superuser shell, your `M2_HOME` environment setting isn't around to muck with the works.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally uploaded swank-clojure to the org.clojure group about a year ago. I deleted it soon after since I'm not associated with that group, so that's why it can't be found. Can I ask where you found the instructions with the erroneous version so it can be corrected?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with lein-ring causing a dependency failure with regard to `org.apache.maven:super-pom`.  Turns out the issue was that `M2_HOME` was set to a version of Maven I use for work.  Unsetting `M2_HOME` fixed the issue.  It appears that leiningen doesn't play nice with strange Maven implementations.

Comment: I had the same super-pom problem with lein, and it turned out the maven-metadata-clojure-releases.xml in the maven cache for clojure was corrupt. It contained the output from lein telling me it didn't know where to find the dependency as it could not connect to my Nexus installation.

Answer (score 0):

With `Ubuntu 10.10 x86_64`, with lein deps, I get annoying 
...
5 required artifacts are missing.

for artifact:

```
org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0
```

...
but the commands

```
sudo LEIN_ROOT=1 ~/bin/lein deps;
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER lib
```

do the job.