# Error when trying to build Clojure boot file in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojurescript

I am starting out with Clojure, and i am currently following the hoplon.io get started tutorial

My troubles start when i try to build boot from source: (http://github.com/tailrecursion/boot)

This is the error that i receive when running the make boot command:

```
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  clojars (http://clojars.org/repo/)
```

I have installed maven but that did not change anything. Has anyone encountered this problem aswell?

Best Regards
Daniel

Comment: Why do you want/need to build boot from source?

Comment: BTW, I just built boot on Ubuntu 12.04 without a problem.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444003/leiningen-missing-super-pom

Comment: I was able to resolve that problem, though now i have a new boot problem with hoplon.. By runnuing: boot development i get these errors: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Network is unreachable